# Convert a Map value to String

Tags: java, groovy, hashmap, httpresponse, katalon-studio

I am trying to convert a map value to `String`. 
I tried `toString()` method but it still returns an `Object` instead of `String`

```
response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('api/test/TD-4_01_01-Valid'))

Map parsed = response.getHeaderFields()

String messageId = parsed.get('x-message-id').toString();

println messageId
```

Actual Output:

```
[C5yZC5hcy5sb2NhbC0xMjgyNi05MzE1LTE=]
```

Expected Output:

```
C5yZC5hcy5sb2NhbC0xMjgyNi05MzE1LTE=
```

Comment: Could you please print the result of `parsed.get('x-message-id').getClass()`

Comment: Probably `x-message-id` value is an array and that result with `[]`.

Comment: @KunLun Arrays don't override `toString` method so that method would return similar result as Object which is `ArrayType@hexHash` not `[value0, value1, ..]`. It is probably some Collection like List or Set.

Comment: I was talking about Collection. But thanks for correcting me.

Comment: What is type of `response` variable? Is it `HttpURLConnection`? If yes then its `.getHeaderFields()` should return `Map<String, List<String>>` and that should be type of `parsed` variable (see: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)). This would allow you to use `parsed.get('x-message-id').get(0);`.

Comment: This is supposed to be https://docs.katalon.com/javadoc/com/kms/katalon/core/testobject/ResponseObject.html#getHeaderFields()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ResponseObject#getHeaderFields returns a `Map` of `String` keys to a `List` of `String` objects as vales. You simply need to get the `List` of `String` objects for the key `x-message-id` and since you expect it to return a single result, find any.

```java
ResponseObject response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('api/test/TD-4_01_01-Valid'));

Map<String, List<String>> parsed = response.getHeaderFields();

List<String> messageIdList = parsed.get("x-message-id");

String messageId = messageIdList.stream().findAny().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [API](https://docs.katalon.com/javadoc/com/kms/katalon/core/testobject/ResponseObject.html#getHeaderFields()), the `Map` is a `Map<String, List<String>>` mapping. This is why you get the wrapping with brackets `[]`.

If you want to access the first element in this list, you should call `parsed.get('x-message-id').get(0)` to access the element with index 0.

Here is the full solution:

```
response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('api/test/TD-4_01_01-Valid'))
Map parsed = response.getHeaderFields()
String messageId = parsed.get('x-message-id').get(0);
println messageId
```

Comment: Almost, but your code will not `.get(0);` method be used on `parsed.get('x-message-id')`.

Comment: You are partially correct. But `x-message-id` can be any type(even a simple string). The creator of question don't tell us the type of `x-message-id`. At first look seems like it's Collection.  `Set` is a `Collection` which don't have `get` method, because don't use index.

Comment: Why a minus vote? Is this not the correct solution? You're mean. >:{

Comment: @Pshemo where do you see the compilation problem?

Comment: hey @HakanDilek messageId is a base64 encoded string.

Comment: Wait, now I noticed that OP used `groovy` as language tag (which I am not familiar with) so I may be wrong if groovy handles generics little different than Java. In Java when we have raw type map like `Map map = ...;` and we use `map.get(key)` we would get as result reference of type `Object` which means we can't use on it methods which don't belong to Object class like `map.get(key).get(index)`. We would need to properly declare `map` as `Map<String, List<String>>` to make it work. Does groovy allow `parsed.get('x-message-id').get(0);` on `Map map`?

Comment: Yes, the map is explicitly defined as a `Map<String, List<String>>` according to the api-doc.

Comment: Yes, it but this is definition of *return type* of a method, but variable you used to store result *from* that method in your code is defined as `Map parsed = response.getHeaderFields()` not `Map<String, List<String>> parsed = response.getHeaderFields()`. In `Java` this would cause problem because *raw* types make method use Object where generic type is missing so `parsed.get('x-message-id')` would return value of `Object` type which doesn't have `get()` method. Does this problem not exist in `groovy`? Does it automatically adds generics to `Map parsed`?

Comment: Using a raw `Map` this way is ok in Groovy.  Generic type specification are not required.